# Call Parent function from iframe then update iframe form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a function in the parent page that needs to be called by an iframe, and this function then updates form value(s) in the iframe. I am able to call the function fine, but form value updating is not working

I setup an alert to see if the parent function could see the input values, but returned undefined, so i assume i am not accessing the ID's correctly

here's my code attempting to auto init today's date in fields split up into three text boxes

Main js function

```
 window.autoPartialDateBox = function(htmlID) {
if ( !jQuery('#'+htmlID+"_mm").val() && !jQuery('#'+htmlID+"_dd").val() && !jQuery('#'+htmlID+"_yy").val() ) {
            var myDate = new Date();    
            jQuery('#'+htmlID+"_mm").val(myDate.getMonth()+1 );                      
            jQuery('#'+htmlID+"_dd").val(myDate.getDate() ); 
            jQuery('#'+htmlID+"_yy").val(myDate.getFullYear() );               
} }
```

iframe

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function () {
        // this will populate the partial date box          
           $("#someElement").live("change", function() {
               if ($(this).val() == 'trigger') {
                window.top.autoPartialDateBox('partial_date_box');
               }

           });

        });
    </script>

Action <select name="someElement" id="someElement" class="valid">
    <option value="" selected="">Select an option</option> 
    <option value="trigger">Trigger</option>            
</select>

Day <input name="stop_dd_2747_mm" type="text" id="stop_dd_2747_mm">
Month <input name="stop_dd_2747_dd" type="text" id="stop_dd_2747_dd" >
Year <input name="stop_dd_2747_yy" type="text" id="stop_dd_2747_yy" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think the issue is accessing the ID, it might be because you are trying to 'build' the ID within the jQuery selector. I think the better solution would be to pass the function a parent element then transverse the node tree to find your input fields.

Function:

```
 window.autoPartialDateBox = function(parentElm) {  

     $nodes = jQuery(parentElm).children('input[type=text]');

     if (!$nodes[0].val() && !$nodes[1].val() && !$nodes[2].val()) {


        var myDate = new Date();    
        $nodes[0].val(myDate.getMonth()+1 );                      
        $nodes[1].val(myDate.getDate() ); 
        $nodes[2].val(myDate.getFullYear() );               
  } 
 }
```

Add a container for your input fields:

```
<div id="input_container">
   Day <input name="stop_dd_2747_mm" type="text" id="stop_dd_2747_mm">
   Month <input name="stop_dd_2747_dd" type="text" id="stop_dd_2747_dd" >
   Year <input name="stop_dd_2747_yy" type="text" id="stop_dd_2747_yy" >
</div>
```

I haven't tested it but that's the general method I would do it. I don't know how jQuery behaves if you try and build a string within the selector. It doesn't seem to be a problem but you never know.

**EDIT** Declared 'nodes' in jQuery namespace

Comment: same error occurs, cannot call method 'val' of undefined. Building a string within a jquery selector works fine when the function is included in the document, it fails when you include it in the top/parent then attempt call

Comment: if the error occurs on the If then you need to check the `.val()` for each child node. `!node[0].val()` and so on. If the error occurs on `node[0].val()` the node needs to be declared in the jQuery namespace with a `$`.

Comment: yea still same error, you think it has todo with the element context? like jQuery('#'+htmlID+"_dd", window.frames[frameName].document).val() doesnt work but should the selector in the parent define the selector with the iframe context?

Comment: Are the input fields in the iFrame or the Top Window?

Comment: If the input fields are in the iFrame, then thats probably the issue. Because call the method from the top window and the elements would exist in the other window.

Comment: yes the input fields are in the iframe, is there a way todo that?

Comment: Yes but you can't just select the elements. You will have to first select the iframe. So if you only have one iframe you could select the elements like this: `$(iframe input[type=text])`